# Angular 2 - Use external library with jquery

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, webpack

I'm using Angular 2 with jQuery and it works well. I'd like to use some external libraries like [masonry-layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/masonry-layout) but i have a problem:

> jQuery(...).masonry() is not a function

I use webpack to get JQuery work.

```
new ProvidePlugin({
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
  })
```

test.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import 'masonry-layout';

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: `
        <div class="container-fluid grid">
            <div class="grid-item">...</div>
            <div class="grid-item">...</div>
            <div class="grid-item">...</div>
            <div class="grid-item">...</div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class TestComponent {
    ngOnInit() {
        jQuery('.grid').masonry();
    }
}
```

Any suggestion ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should change your import to:

```
import 'masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd';
```

Seems configuration changes don't work for this library:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  $: 'jquery',
  jquery: 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery' <== this line
}),
```

[image]
So you can try the following:

```
window.jQuery = jQuery;
import 'masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd';
```